# PHP Dynamic menu highlight from database

Tags: php, database, url, navigation, highlight

I've been making a website for a client that is based off of 1 page and the links are to different categories or articles. I'm showing the content depending on the URL parameter like this,

`<a href="index.php?cat_id=<?php echo $category['cat_id']" >`

usually to do a navigation highlight depending on the page I would do something like this,

**PHP**

```
<ul>
    <li <?php if($pagename == "index.php"){ echo 'class="selected"'; } ?>>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li <?php if($pagename == "about.php"){ echo 'class="selected"'; } ?>>
        <a href="about.php">About</a>
    </li>
    <li <?php if($pagename == "services.php"){ echo 'class="selected"'; } ?>>
         <a href="services.php">Services</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

but my URLS are dynamic from the database like so,

**PHP**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <?php while ($category = $statement->fetch()) { ?>
        <li><a href="index.php?cat_id=<?php echo $category['cat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $category['cat_name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php 
         }  
    ?>
</ul>
```

So I was wondering how can I add the class `selected` to the links `cat_id` when the URL contains that parameters id? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the category IDs do not change over time:

```
if($_GET['category_id'] == "1" ){ echo 'class="selected"'; }
```

If the categorie IDs are subject to change over time, you will need to perform a pre-query to get a map of category IDs to pages. Then you can do something like:

```
if($_GET['category_id'] == $categories['home_page'] ){ echo 'class="selected"'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if($category['cat_id']==$_GET['cat_id']){ echo 'class="selected"';}?>
```